# Detecting stroked uibezierpath contains point

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uibezierpath

I'm drawing a stroked path in my view. And I'm trying to see if the stroked path contains a specific point. But it the contains method does not detect if the point is in the stroked path.

```
func checkCollision(currentPoint:CGPoint) -> CustomShape?{
    for shape in customShapes {
        //Check if current shapes uibezierpath contains a point
        if (shape.path.contains(currentPoint)) {
            return shape
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: do you mean... a) the point lies inside the closed path, b) the point was programatically added to the path at some time in the past... or c) the point theoretically exactly intersects the path?

Comment: @BooberBunz The point intersects with the path.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.x

You can use this extension for a quick answer:

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    func isInsideBorder(_ pos:CGPoint, tolleranceWidth:CGFloat = 2.0)->Bool{
        let pathRef = cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: tolleranceWidth, lineCap: CGLineCap.butt, lineJoin: CGLineJoin.round, miterLimit: 0)
        let pathRefMutable = pathRef.mutableCopy()
        if let p = pathRefMutable {
            p.closeSubpath()
            return p.contains(pos)
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

---

### Usage:

```
var currentPoint:CGPoint= CGPoint.zero
if yourBeizerPath.isInsideBorder(currentPoint, tolleranceWidth:3.0) {
   /// Let's go, it's inside..
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Override the `hitTest(_:with:)` instance method of your custom `UIView`. This method returns the view object that is the farthest descendent of the current view and contains `point`. It returns `nil` if the point lies completely outside the receiver’s view hierarchy.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    guard path.contains(point) else {
        return nil
    }
    return self
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One way to check if a point is inside a stroked path is to do a copy of the path and add a stroke using cgPath's copy method.

```
let strokedPath = yourPath.cgPath.copy(
   strokingWithWidth: 10, 
   lineCap: CGLineCap.butt, 
   lineJoin: CGLineJoin.miter, 
   miterLimit: 0
)
```